# How do i get sites by group handle/name?

Tags: templating

How can I get sites by their group handle/name within twig templates?
Documentation only mentions querying sites by group id - `getSitesByGroupId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a reference to a [`Site` model](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-models-site.html) (i.e. the [global `currentSite` Twig variable](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/global-variables.html#currentsite)), you can get other sites in that group, like this:

```
{% set currentSiteGroup = currentSite.group %}
{% set sitesInGroup = currentSiteGroup.sites %}

{# Bonus — Remove the current site from that list: #}
{% set otherSitesInGroup = sitesInGroup|without(currentSite) %}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would rather suggest you to do that in PHP but the Twig way would be the following

```TWIG
{% set allSites = craft.app.getSites().getAllSites() %}
{% set sitesWithGroup = [] %}
{% for site in allSites %}
    {% if site.getGroup().name == 'my group name' %}
        {% set sitesWithGroup = sitesWithGroup|merge([site]) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think i will turn it into macro. And about php, i prefear to do things in twig when its possible, its just less posibility to break something.

Comment: Wait, I can't make macro using this, macro returns only strings. Oh, well.

Comment: That's why you usually want to do it in PHP since it's less likely to break and you have more possiblies + it's less resource heavy

Answer (score 1):

I find Twig/Craft filters to be the most concise and readable for things like this.

```
{% set allSites = craft.app.sites.getAllSites() %}
{% set filteredSites = allSites|filter(s => s.group == 'My Group Name') %}
```

More useful filters [here](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/filters.html)